# How can I alter an array from inside a function in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, physics, numerical-integration

I am trying to write a c++ rk4 algorithm and I seem to be running into the same error no matter what I try. I can compile the program but I keep getting a `zsh: segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./main`. I believe that the problem is within the rk4 function here:

```cpp
void funcs::rk4(double *p_vec, double h)
{

    double *k0, *k1, *k2, *k3, *l0, *l1, *l2;


    k0 = force( p_vec );

    for ( int inst = 0; inst < 2; ++inst )
    {
        l0[ inst ] = p_vec[ inst ] + h*( k0[ inst ] );
    }

    k1 = force( l0 );

    for ( int inst = 0; inst < 2; ++inst )
    {
        l1[ inst ] = p_vec[ inst ] + ( h/2 ) * ( k1[ inst ] );
    }

    k2 = force( l1 );

    for ( int inst = 0; inst < 2; ++inst )
    {
        l2[ inst ] = p_vec[ inst ] + ( h/2 ) * ( k2[ inst ] );
    }

    k3 = force( l2 );

    for ( int inst = 0; inst < 2; ++inst )
    {
        ( p_vec )[ inst ] += ( ( k0[ inst ] ) + 2*( k1[ inst ] ) + 2* ( k2[ inst ] ) + ( k3[ inst ] ) )*( h/6 );

    }

}
```

Here is the main function as well if that helps:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include "functions.h"

using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    float alpha = 0, beta = 1;
    int Number = 1000;
    double h = ( beta - alpha )/ Number;
    double postiton_0 = 1.0, velocity_0 = 0.0;

    vector<double> time = funcs::linspace( alpha, beta, Number );
    double p_vector[2] = { postiton_0, velocity_0 };

    for ( int inst = 0; inst <= Number; ++inst )
    {
        funcs::rk4( p_vector, h );

        cout << inst << ", " << p_vector[ 0 ]
            << ", " << p_vector[ 1 ] << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit:

Thank you for the quick responses!

Here is the source for the source:

```cpp
double * funcs::force(double *p_vec)
{
    double force_position = p_vec[ 0 ], force_velocity = p_vec[ 1 ];
    static double force_p_vec[ 2 ];

    double force_acceleration = -force_position*force_position;

    force_p_vec[ 0 ] = force_velocity;
    force_p_vec[ 1 ] = force_acceleration;

    return force_p_vec;
}
```

The thing is that when I try to run the force function without rk4 I do get numbers out, maybe it is the way I am working with the pointers. Is there any way that I can do without them? Thanks.

UPDATE:

I decided to take the advice of not using pointers and dynamic memory allocation and used this code:

```cpp
void funcs::rk4(double *p_vec, double h)
{

    double temp[ 2 ];

    double *k0 = force( p_vec );

    for ( int inst = 0; inst < 2; ++inst )
    {
        temp[ inst ] = p_vec[ inst ] + h*( k0[ inst ] );
    }

    double *k1 = force( temp );

    for ( int inst = 0; inst < 2; ++inst )
    {
        temp[ inst ] = p_vec[ inst ] + ( h/2 ) * ( k1[ inst ] );
    }

    double *k2 = force( temp );

    for ( int inst = 0; inst < 2; ++inst )
    {
        temp[ inst ] = p_vec[ inst ] + ( h/2 ) * ( k2[ inst ] );
    }

    double *k3 = force( temp );

    for ( int inst = 0; inst < 2; ++inst )
    {
        p_vec[ inst ] += ( ( k0[ inst ] ) + 2*( k1[ inst ] ) + 2* ( k2[ inst ] ) + ( k3[ inst ] ) )*( h/6 );

    }

}
```

I get numbers, but they explode to infinity which is not the intended effect. This is a simple harmonic oscillator. The position and velocity should oscillate between 1 and 0. I am using the same force function.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the source of `force` please? I have the suspiecion it's something along the lines `double *force(double v[3]){double r[3]; …; return r;}` which is something that invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: You have a lot of pointers (like for example `l0`) but you never make them point anywhere. Perhaps you might need to study more about pointers, arrays and their relationship. And learn how to use the facilities provided by the C++ standard library, like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Yes, `l0[ inst ] = ...` **Undefined Behavior** - The thing is, you don't even need one single pointer or any manual memory management to do this. It only makes things a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A problem that still remains even with the latest version of `funcs::rk4()` is that all your pointers (`k0` ... `k3`) point to the same static buffer inside `funcs::force()`. Therefore, when you are computing

```
p_vec[ inst ] += ( ( k0[ inst ] ) + 2*( k1[ inst ] ) + 2* ( k2[ inst ] ) + ( k3[ inst ] ) )*( h/6 );
```

all of `k0` ... `k3` actually have contents of `k3`.

So, you need `funcs::force()` return an array rather than a pointer. As you know, you can't return C-style array. You can, however, return `std::array`. Your function becomes

```
std::array<double, 2> funcs::force(double *p_vec)
{
    double force_position = p_vec[ 0 ], force_velocity = p_vec[ 1 ];
    std::array<double, 2>  force_p_vec; //non-static!

    double force_acceleration = -force_position*force_position;

    force_p_vec[ 0 ] = force_velocity;
    force_p_vec[ 1 ] = force_acceleration;

    return force_p_vec;
}
```

Each of `k0` ... `k3` inside `funcs::rk4()` should also be declared `std::array<double, 2>` instead of `double`.